# Writing a program to continue to ints until a prime

Tags: c

Write a program to continue to read in positive integers
till a prime is encountered. Assume at least one number will be entered.

Eg.

> Please enter #: 8
>   Please enter #: 9
>  
>   Please enter #: 10 
>   Please enter #: 11
>   Thanks you entered a prime, bye.

The main problem that I am having is the continuation until the prime occurs. The code I have to test if the number is prime is here:

```
// PRIME NUMBER TEST
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int number, n, is_prime = 0;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    for (n=2; n<=number/2; n++) {

        if (number%n==0)
            is_prime = 1;

        while(is_prime == 1) {
              printf("Enter #: ");
              scanf("%d", &number);

    }
   }


    if (is_prime == 0)
        printf("%d is a prime number.\n", number);

     system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I know that it would be a for loop to keep it going and just initializing a counter until the prime occurs, but for whatever reason I just can't get it right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Always post the code that you have so far, and be very specific about what it is that isn't working right. Go so far as to include things you've tried, whether they worked or not.

Comment: The posted code is in the paste bin link. I have tried to do a while loop such as: while (is_prime == 1) and then re-prompting the user for the number.

Comment: I don't see a while loop in the code you posted..

Comment: I've moved it inline, into the question. Add your extra commentary directly in the question via the edit link.

Comment: ... Maybe you got the while-loop and for-loop inside out....try changing that....

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. do you mean having: while(n<=input/2)..etc and having the for loop: for(n = 2; is_prime == 1; n++) ???

Comment: `is_prime` is not changing inside the while-loop, so how do you expect it to ever exit -- or actually in the code you posted it will probably never enter...

Comment: The best thing to take from this post is: what pieces of information were needed by potential helpers. A short description of the actual issue you're having. The code you've got. Theories you've formed/things you've tried. Errors you've encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to walk though your code and check your invariant for each loop, that is what I mean by my comment of that your for-while loops are inside out....

```
// PRIME NUMBER TEST
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    bool is_prime = false;
    while(is_prime == false) {
        int number, n;
        printf("Enter #: ");
        scanf("%d", &number); // scanf is not recommended, but use it here anyway

        is_prime = true; // we assume so for now, also test for numbers < 2
        for (n=2; n<=number/2; n++) // this can be optimized, but leave as is anyway
           if (number%n==0)
              is_prime = false; // sorry it was not prime

    }
    printf("%d is a prime number.\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```